# How to SUM column if same value

Tags: sql

I have query to SUM and COUNT my table, but i have trouble, i want to SUM column name after COUNT it. 
This is my table...

```
id  no_reg  name        date       qty
1   REG01   T-212-BS    2019-05-03  1
2   REG01   T-212-BS    2019-05-03  1
3   REG01   T-212-BS    2019-05-03  1
4   REG01   T-212-BA    2019-05-03  1
5   REG02   T-111-AA    2019-05-04  1
6   REG03   T-111-AB    2019-05-04  1
```

I create query....

```
SELECT     no_reg, COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS Name_qty, date, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM         part
GROUP BY no_reg, name, date, qty
```

and result of query after execution...

```
no_reg   Name_qty   date        qty
REG01     1         2019-05-03  1
REG01     1         2019-05-03  3
REG02     1         2019-05-04  1
REG03     1         2019-05-04  1
```

But, I want results like this...

```
no_reg   Name_qty   date        qty
REG01     2         2019-05-03  4
REG02     1         2019-05-04  1
REG03     1         2019-05-04  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to group by name, even if you're using it in your distinct statement.

```
SELECT     no_reg, COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS Name_qty, date, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM         part
GROUP BY no_reg, date
```

Answer (score 1):

You're grouping by `qty`, so any rows that do not have the same `qty` will be aggregated separately. Since `qty` is used in an aggregate function, you can remove it from the group by and it should give you the expected results

```sql
SELECT no_reg, COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS Name_qty, date, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM part
GROUP BY no_reg, date
```

**EDIT**:

I also noticed that name was included in the group by. You can remove it too since it is used in the count aggregate